# Updates to Stanley's 1999 survey of positivity problems in algebraic combinatorics?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, open-problems, algebraic-combinatorics

[I am a co-moderator of the recently started [Open Problems in Algebraic Combinatorics blog](https://realopacblog.wordpress.com/) and as a result starting doing some searching for existing surveys of open problems in algebraic combinatorics.]

In 1999 R. Stanley wrote a very nice survey on open problems in algebraic combinatorics, with a specific focus on positivity, called "Positivity problems and conjectures in algebraic combinatorics", available [online here](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/problems.pdf). It includes 25 specific open problems, as well as a lot of discussion/context.

**Question**: 20 years later, which problems from Stanley's list have been resolved?

On his website he has a page with [updates](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/problems_update.html) from 2004, but still, even 2004 was 15 years ago.

Comment: Problem 10 has seen partial cases resolved, such as in [this paper by Jonah Blasiak and Ricky Liu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00644).

Comment: I believe I have a quite updated list of progress made on the Stanley-Stembridge (Shareshian-Wachs) conjecture: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/chromaticQuasisymmetric.htm#chromaticEExpansionCurrentStatus

Comment: I created a meta thread to discuss the appropriateness of this question/answer pair (both by the same author, by the way): https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4423/are-questions-appropriate-if-they-require-answers-to-be-edited-in-perpetuity?cb=1

Comment: Analogously: [Thurston's 24 questions: All settled?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/265493/6094). Spoiler: In some sense, all but #23.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: yes, that one was mentioned on meta.

Answer (score 37):

I'm posting a community wiki answer to compile all the known information about the status of all the problems.

**Problem 1** (The Generalized Lower Bound Theorem/g-theorem for Gorenstein* complexes): In December 2018, Adiprasito posted a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10454) (see also this [summary](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/rendiconti/40_2_(2019)_97-111.html)) announcing a proof of the g-theorem for homology spheres that are also homology manifolds, which are the same thing as Gorenstein* complexes.

**Problem 2** (The GLBT for toric h-vectors of polytopes/Gorenstein* lattices): [Karu](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-004-0358-3) established the GLBT for toric h-vectors of arbitrary convex polytopes. It would seem the extension to Gorenstein* lattices remains open though, and is discussed in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-012-9449-x) of Billera and Nevo.

**Problems 3 and 3'** (Kalai's $3^d$ conjecture for $f$-vectors of centrally symmetric polytopes): It would seem this is still open (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalai%27s_3%5Ed_conjecture)). Some stronger versions of the conjecture were disproved by [Sanyal-Werner-Ziegler](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-008-9104-8). The latest discussion I can find is in [Freij-Henze-Schmitt-Ziegler](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p32).

**Problem 4** (The Charney-Davis conjecture on $h$-vectors of flag spheres): This seems wide-open still. In dimensions $\leq 3$ it has been proved by [Davis and Okun](https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2001.5.7). The most significant progress for arbitrary dimensions is work of [Gal](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-005-1171-5) in which he defines the $\gamma$-vector of a flag complex as the "right" analog of the $g$-vector for flag complexes, and conjectures that the $\gamma$-vector of a flag generalized homology sphere is nonnegative. This would in particular imply the Charney-Davis conjecture (which is essentially the statement that a particular coefficient in the $\gamma$-vector is nonnegative). See this nice survey of [Zheng](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789811200489_0028).

**Problem 5** (A generalization of the decomposition of acyclic complexes to "$k$-fold" acyclic complexes): This conjecture of Stanley was resolved in the negative by [Doolittle and Goeckner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08518).

**Problem 6** (Are Cohen-Macaulay complexes partitionable?): This conjecture of Stanley and Garsia was resolved in the negative by [Duval–Goeckner–Klivans–Martin](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2016.05.011).

**Problem 7** (Positivity of the cd-index of a Gorenstein* poset): This was proved by [Karu](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X06001928).

**Problem 8** (Positivity of cubical $h$-vectors of Cohen-Macaulay cubical complexes): I believe that this is still open. The one significant result I can find is that [Athanasiadis](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10801-011-0306-4) has proved that for a Cohen-Macaulay cubical complex of dimension $d$ (or more generally a Cohen-Macaulay cubical poset) we have $h^{(c)}_{d-1}\geq 0$ (that $h^{(c)}_{d}\geq 0$ is easy).

**Problem 9** (Combinatorial interpretation of plethysm coefficients): Still wide-open in general but solved in many special cases. The maximal and minimal constituents of an arbitrary plethysm were found by [Paget and Wildon](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms.12210); this article has a survey of the main results known in 2016. Some relations between plethysm coefficients, generalizing results of Brion, Bruns–Conca–Varbaro, Ikenmeyer, and Paget–Wildon, are in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03448). Foulkes' Conjecture is the special case that $h_m \circ h_n - h_n \circ h_m$ is Schur positive when $m \ge n$: it is known when $m \le 5$ ([Cheung–Ikenmeyer–Mkrtchyan](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2016.09.002)) and when $m$ is large compared to $n$ ([Brion](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03026558)).

**Problem 10** (Combinatorial interpretation of Kroenecker coefficients): Still wide-open in general. But some special cases are known, such as when some of the partitions are hooks or two-rowed shapes (see [Blasiak and Liu](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2018.02.007) and its references).

**Problem 11** (Combinatorial interpretation of Schubert polynomial structure constants): Still wide-open in general. But some special cases are known, such as some cases of "Schur times Schubert" (see [Mészáros–Panova–Postnikov](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i1p39)).

**Problem 12** (Combinatorial interpretation of row sums of the character table of the symmetric group): Still open in general.  Some special cases are discussed by Baker and Early in "Character Polynomials and Row Sums of the Symmetric Group", see [here](http://edwarde.create.stedwards.edu/rowsums.pdf), and Sundaram in "The conjugacy action of $S_n$ and modules induced from centralisers", see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05898).

**Problem 13** (The Macdonald positivity conjecture): This was resolved by [Haiman](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-01-00373-3), using advanced machinery from algebraic geometry like the Hilbert scheme of points. A combinatorial interpretation of the $(q,t)$-Kostka polynomials remains elusive in general, but there are some partial results (see e.g. this paper of [Assaf](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v25i2p44)).

**Problem 14** (LLT polynomials- combinatorial proof of symmetry, and Schur positivity): The Schur positivity of LLT polynomials was proved by Grojnowski and Haiman in an [unpublished manuscript](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/llt-positivity/new-version.pdf) from 2006. I imagine a combinatorial proof of the symmetry of these polynomials remains open.

**Problem 15** (Positivity of the coefficients of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials for arbitrary Coxeter groups): This was resolved by the work of [Elias and Williamson](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2014.180.3.6) on Soergel bimodules.

**Problem 16** (Combinatorial interpretation of the coefficients of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials for Weyl groups/affine Weyl groups): ???

**Problems 17, 17', 18** (Total positivity and Schur positivity of monomial immanants): These are apparently open (for instance, Stanley notes that an affirmative answer to Problem 17 would imply one for Problem 21), but some special cases are addressed in the work of [Clearman–Shelton–Skandera](https://dmtcs.episciences.org/2906).

**Problem 19** (Positivity/symmetry/unimodality of monomial characters of Hecke algebra evaluated on Kazhdan-Lusztig basis elements): According to [Clearman–Hyatt–Shelton–Skandera](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v23i2p7), this is still open (or at least was in 2016).

**Problems 20 and 20'** (The Stanley-Neggers conjecture about real rootedness of poset descent polynomials): Counterexamples to these conjectures were first found by [Brändén](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1079-6762-04-00140-4) and [Stembridge](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-06-04271-1). (As explained in the survey by Stanley, Problem 20' about chain polynomials is equivalent to Problem 20 and hence also has a negative answer.)

**Problem 21** (The Stanley-Stembridge conjecture about e-positivity of chromatic symmetric functions of (3+1)-free posets): This is currently a hot topic, and still open, although many special cases are known as [documented here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/chromaticQuasisymmetric.htm#chromaticEExpansionCurrentStatus). The most significant advances on the problem are a result of [Guay-Paquet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2400) which reduces the conjecture to the case of (3+1)- and (2+2)-free posets, i.e., unit interval orders; as well as work of [Shareshian and Wachs](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-88-7642-431-1_20),  [Brosnan and Chow](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2018.02.020), and [Guay-Paquet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05498), which connects the conjecture to the cohomology of Hessenberg varieties.

**Problems 22** (Gasharov's conjecture about s-positivity of chromatic symmetric functions of claw-free graphs): ???

**Problem 23** (Real-rootedness of stable set polynomials of claw-free graphs): This was proved by [Chudnovsky and Seymour](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2006.06.001).

**Problem 24** (The Monotone Column Permanent Conjecture): Solved by [Brändén–Haglund–Visontai–Wagner](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-0142-3_5) using the theory of real stable polynomials.

**Problem 25** (Unimodality/log concavity of (a) coefficients of characteristic polynomial of graph/matroid, (b) number of size $i$ independent sets of graph/matroid, (c) rank sizes of a geometric lattice): For graphs, (the absolute value of) the coefficients of the chromatic polynomial were shown to be log-concave by [Huh](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2012-00731-0); this was extended to realizable matroids by  [Huh–Katz](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-011-0777-6); and then to all matroids by [Adiprasito–Huh–Katz](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2018.188.2.1). The result for the characteristic polynomial actually implies the result for independent sets, as observed by [Lenz](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2013.07.001) using a result of [Brylawski](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1977-0468931-6). The unimodality of the rank sizes of a geometric lattice (i.e., the so-called "Whitney numbers of the second kind") is apparently a harder question and remains open: see section 5.10 of [this survey of Baker](https://doi.org/10.1090/bull/1599). But ``half'' of the conjecture has been proved (i.e., that the rank sizes increase up to halfway), in the case of realizable matroids by [Huh–Wang](https://doi.org/10.4310/ACTA.2017.v218.n2.a2), and in the case of arbitrary matroids in this preprint of [Braden–Huh–Matherne–Proudfoot–Wang](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.06088).

Comment: I took the liberty of converting all the raw URLs to hyperlinks, which I think makes the text much more readable.

Comment: Problem 23 on the zeros of stable set polynomials of clawfree graphs was solved by Chudnovsky and Seymour at https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mchudnov/roots.pdf.

Comment: Gorenstein* simplicial complexes are the same as homology spheres that are also homology manifolds, which are discussed in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10454); I just stuck to the more classical notation (which is admittedly more of a mouthful, but also self-explanatory). [Here](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/rendiconti/40_2_(2019)_97-111.html) is also a simpler overview over the proof

Comment: @KarimAdiprasito: thanks so much! Updated to reflect this.

Comment: Also Davis and Okun showed Charney-Davis for spheres up to Dimension 3

Comment: @KarimAdiprasito: added, thanks!

Comment: Sami Assaf has been working on a combinatorial solution of Problem 13 for some time.  Judging from her introduction in https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07457 it looks like this has only been established thus far in special cases. (Her earlier claim to combinatorially resolve Problems 13, 14 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3759 unfortunately had some gaps.)

Comment: @TerryTao: thanks, added!

Comment: @KarimAdiprasito: according to WIkipedia definitions, a homology sphere is a homology manifold (in fact, a topological manifold). A Gorenstein* simplicial complex is a triangulation of a homology manifold whose Euler characteristic is the same as that of a sphere (of the same dimension).

Comment: @RichardStanley Gorenstein* satisfies Poincare duality in the face ring. Euler characteristic is not enough for that. In fact, I am only citing your book here (in the characteristic 0 case), see Theorem 5.1 in R.P. Stanley, Combinatorics and commutative algebra Progress in Mathematics 41, Birkhauser, 1996. The      important thing here is the distinction between a homology manifold and a topological one, as in a homological one the links only need the homology ring of a sphere. This is what then I mean a homology manifold that is also a homology sphere.

Comment: (added because space ran out: I am restricting to a fixed characteristic here when speaking about these equivalences).                                                                                In my way of saying it:

A (closed) homology manifold is a simplicial complex whose proper links have the homology of a sphere. If you want boundary, you can include balls, but let us leave that for now.

A homology sphere that is a homology manifold is a homology manifold that has the homology of a sphere. This coincides with Gorenstein*.

Comment: @KarimAdiprasito: Oops, I meant to say that a Gorenstein* simplicial complex is a triangulation of a homology manifold whose homology (not Euler characteristic) is the same as that of a sphere.

Comment: @RichardStanley Yes, that is also the notation I used in the paper, it is better. To summarize, given a field F: Gorenstein* (over F) = A homology manifold that has the homology of a sphere (over F). Thanks

Comment: A proof of symmetry of LLTs is not that difficult - it relies on a recursion, which is fairly easy. But the question is if this counts as combinatorial... My point is, symmetry of LLTs can be proved by means which do not use Haiman's result