Examples of combinatorial problems where the only known solutions, or most "natural" solutions, use representation theory?
In Solution of two difficult combinatorial problems with linear algebra, Robert Proctor presents two simply stated combinatorial problems, and gives solutions to them using a linear algebraic approach that is motivated by the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. Moreover, he notes that this application is in some sense natural and inherent here, because both problems being considered are equivalently formulated as asking whether certain posets meet the conditions of being "rank unimodal" and "Sperner," and any poset satisfying these two conditions together with some additional symmetry constraints carries a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$.
My question: beyond the problems discussed in the link above and the references therein, are there other examples of combinatorial problems whose only known solution, or whose most motivated and natural solution, employs representation theory?

There are many examples. In many cases the only reason we know some quantity is positive (e.g. plethysm coefficients, Kronecker coefficients, Schubert polynomial structure constants, row sums of character tables of $S_n$) is because of representation theory and/or algebraic geometry. This is even though these quantities have purely combinatorial descriptions. See Stanley's classic survey on positivity problems in algebraic combinatorics (https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/problems.pdf) and my related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349406.

Do you want to include the proviso that the problem itself can't be expressed in a more  motivated and natural way using representation-theoretic language? Several quantities in representation theory (e.g. characters of the symmetric group) have purely combinatorial formulas for them. Every property these quantities satisfy can therefore be expressed as the resolution of a combinatorial problem. For many properties the most motivated and natural proof surely uses representation theory. Is this an example of what you want?

Maybe for quantities that are most naturally defined representation-theoretically, the interesting question is if there is any combinatorial proof (as Sam was discussing https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481722/examples-of-combinatorial-problems-where-the-only-known-solutions-or-most-natu#comment1254417_481722) but for quantities that are most naturally defined combinatorially one can ask if the most natural proof is representation-theoretic.

Another place to look: Stanley's list of Bijective Proof Problems (https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf). Problems marked [*] have no combinatorial proofs. Of course, not all of the non-combinatorial proofs here are from representation theory, but many are.

If you count construction of expander graphs then sure, Lubotzky-Phillips-Sarnak/Margulis

Thanks everyone for the examples! In reply to Will Sawin's question, yes my main interest is in problems which can be stated naturally (and ideally were already being studied independently) without invoking representation theoretic language.

For those not familiar with Proctor's work, here is perhaps the most easily stated example of a result that is (arguably) most naturally proved using the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$: The coefficients of the polynomial $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^n)$ form a unimodal sequence. I believe that there is still no really simple combinatorial proof of this fact. One can "dismantle" the representation-theoretic proof to make it more "elementary", as Proctor does, but the result is still a rather complicated proof.

For a partition $\lambda$, let $y_k(\lambda)$ denote the number of Standard Young Tableaux $T$ of shape $\lambda$ satisfying $\mathrm{maj}(T)\equiv 1 \mod k$. (Here $\mathrm{maj}(T)$ is the major index of $T$, the sum of the descents of $T$, where $i$ is a descent of $T$ if $i$ appears in a row above $i+1$ in $T$.)
Then, according to Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. 2, Chapter 7 Exercise 7.88(d), there is no known combinatorial proof of the fact that $y_{n-1}(\lambda) \geq y_n(\lambda)$ for any partition $\lambda\vdash n$, although there is a proof using the representation theory of the symmetric group $S_n$.
I found this by searching for the phrase "no combinatorial proof is known" in EC1 and EC2.

Here's an example I found by searching "combinatorial proof" in Stanley's supplemental problems to EC2 Chapter 7: see here for the problems and here for the solutions.
If you look at the solution to problem 106(b) there, you will see Stanley notes that it implies
$$ \#\{(u,v)\in S_n\times S_n\colon uv = vu\} = \#\{(u,v)\in S_n \times S_n \colon u^2=v^2 \}.$$
Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters. The proof is via some symmetric function identities and Stanley remarks that the same is true for any finite group $G$ all of whose complex representations are equivalent to real representations.
He asks there if there is a combinatorial proof of this identity. I have no idea if this is easy.
EDIT: This is Exercise 108(b) in the Supplementary Problems of Chapter 7 as in the published version of the 2nd edition of EC2.

See also supplementary problem 43 and Theorem A2.2.2.

I didn't notice that the numbering of the supplementary problems in the second edition of EC2 differs from the numbering in the online PDF that you linked to. When I said "problem 43" I meant problem 43 in the second edition of EC2. In the online PDF, this is problem 42.

I'm not sure it's worth posting as a separate answer, because it's not a problem that anyone would think to study without already knowing the representation theory of the symmetric group. But the statement is this: if we multiply the Schur function $s_\lambda$ by the product of the hook lengths of $\lambda$, and express the result in terms of power-sum symmetric functions, then the coefficients are integers.

This is a special case  (namely, the case $x = e$)  of a question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365476/writing-a-group-element-as-ghg-1-h-1-and-as-g2-h2which I asked at math.SE and which got good answers:

@DavidESpeyer: Nice! So it is possible to give a proof avoiding character theory.

Many special cases of the Černý conjecture in automata theory have been proved using linear algebra, or really representations of monoids, that do not have known combinatorial proofs.  The conjecture states that an $n$-state synchronizing automaton has a synchronizing word of length at most $(n-1)^2$.  In purely mathematical terms the conjecture states that given a set of transformations of an $n$-element set, of which some composition  (with repetitions allowed) is a constant map, then some composition of length at most $(n-1)^2$ is a constant map.
Many proof analyze the corresponding linear representation of the monoid generated by these transformations. My favorite example is the paper of Dubuc, which proves the conjecture is true if one of the transformations is an $n$-cycle. Černý had already shown that the bound can be reached by examples with an $n$-cycle. Dubuc uses the nature of representations of the cyclic group over the rationals (or if you like uses minimal polynomials). But there are many more such examples.
