# Progress on a problem list

Tags: soft-question, journals

There is a list of open problems in my sub-field that was published in a journal some time ago and has had an impact on the area.

Many of the problems have been solved, some have partial solutions, and some are still unsolved.

I am considering trying to write a survey of the current status of this list. However, I am concerned about a few publication-related questions:

(1) Can my survey reproduce the statements of the problems? Of course I would not take credit for the problems, but I am concerned that I would be reproducing a large proportion of the content of a published paper.

(2) Is the answer to Question (1) different if I am trying to publish the survey in a journal vs. just post on arxiv vs. just post to my website?

(Regarding (2), it may be that no journal would be interested; that is a secondary concern.)

(3) Can anyone point to examples of surveys like this, in any area of mathematics? (Surveys discussing the current status of a list of problems in a specialized area. Surveys and books about the Clay Millennium Problems abound, but how about more specialized examples?)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about published papers, but there have been a few MO questions like what you're suggesting: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349406 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265493; but note they got some pushback on meta: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4423.

Comment: Oh now I see that the question about Thurston's list actually does link to a paper like you're talking about: https://doi.org/10.1365/s13291-014-0079-5.

Comment: There are a couple of books surveying the Hilbert problems, but that fails your "specialized area" requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q3:** A classic of this type is [Erdős on Graphs : His Legacy of Unsolved Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156881111X)

> This book is a tribute to Paul Erdős, the wandering mathematician once
>   described as the "prince of problem solvers and the absolute monarch
>   of problem posers." It examines the legacy of open problems he left to
>   the world after his death in 1996.

<sub>**Q1:** of course you will want to reproduce the open problems themselves, to make the survey self-contained.

**Q2:** such reproduction falls under "fair use" of published material, so it can be included in a publication without copyright infringement.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I accepted this answer of Carlo Beenakker because it answered all three parts of my question. I appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

**Q3:** For group theory, you will probably not find many more comprehensive surveys like this than the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/); this has been active since 1965, and is regularly updated with new problems, which problems have been solved, and a quick reference to where the solution appears.

> Problems have been proposed by hundreds of mathematicians from all over the world, the difficulty of problems ranges from PhD level to well-known problems that remain open for decades. More than fifty years “Kourovka Notebook” serves as a unique means of communication for researchers in Group Theory and nearby fields of mathematics. Probably the most striking illustration of its success is the fact that more than three-quarters of the problems from the 1st edition of 1965 have now been solved.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This is a great project.